# Find first day of previous month in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given a date object, how to get its previous month's first day in javascript

Comment: a more descriptive title might be nice...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594054/date-problem-in-java looks like your previous question was for java. so not exactly a duplicate :)

Comment: Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) `moment().subtract(1, "months").startOf("months").toDate()`.

Answer (score 54):

```
function firstDayInPreviousMonth(yourDate) {
    var d = new Date(yourDate);
    d.setDate(1);
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
    return d;
}
```

EDIT:  Alright...  I've definitely learned something here.  I think that this is the simplest solution that covers all cases (and yes, it does work for January):

```
function firstDayInPreviousMonth(yourDate) {
    return new Date(yourDate.getFullYear(), yourDate.getMonth() - 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will FAIL for something like: firstDayInPreviousMonth(new Date("Mar 31 2009")). See the comments on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499838/javascript-date-next-month

Comment: It wouldn't fail if he setDate(1) before doing the setMonth()

Comment: -1 getYear() is broken you should be using getFullYear() instead

Comment: Good catch @JK. Not sure how that slipped in there.

Comment: @Prestaul

Sorry to bring up an old post, but could you please explain how: `return new Date(yourDate.getFullYear(), yourDate.getMonth() - 1, 1)` works?

I know it works, but can't get my head around as to how it handles January. If I ran it today (28/01/2014) wouldn't it return (01/00/2014)?

Comment: @Chronix3, first of all, `getMonth`, `setMonth` and the `Date` constructor use zero-based months (weird, I know) so January is represented as zero, Feb as 1, etc. The real magic here is that the js Date object is flexible enough to compensate for dates that are out of range by wrapping to next or previous months. For example, `Date(2014, 0, 31)` = Jan 31, `Date(2014, 0, 32)` = Feb 1, `Date(2014, -1, 25)` = Dec 25 2013. This is to allow for math to be performed easily. For example, I can always increment a day using `dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1)`.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know how flexible the js Date object was. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 16):

The following should work:

```
now = new Date();
if (now.getMonth() == 0) {
    current = new Date(now.getFullYear() - 1, 11, 1);
} else {
    current = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, 1);
}
```

keeping in mind that months are zero-based so December is *11* rather than 12.

But, as others have pointed out, the month wraps, even as part of the atomic constructor, so the following is also possible:

```
now = new Date();
firstDayPrevMonth = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, 1);
```

Comment: I like this approach, but your solution actually isn't correct.  When getMonth() == 1, the month is February.  You want to check for getMonth() == 0, and even that isn't required because the Date constructor will accept negative values and work correctly.

Comment: You're neglecting the fact that setMonth will wrap values. Prestaul's answer works fine for January.

Comment: Yes, but not for moving back to a month where the number of days is less, unfortunately. It's better to construct the new date atomically rather than piecemeal.

Comment: Considering the Mar 31 example, you are correct about the anatomical date construction - if you change your answer (I do find the "blindly subtracting a month" line to be misleading given javascript's setXXX wrapping) I'll be happy to adjust my vote on this answer.

Comment: I agree.  You'll get my vote as well if you remove the test for January.

Comment: As you wish ... I had to check it was okay in the constructor as well, rather than just for setMonth().

Comment: +1...  I love StackOverflow because the best answer usually does find its way to the top!

Comment: -1 `getYear()` is broken you should be using `getFullYear()` instead

Comment: Good catch, @JK, fixed it for you :-)

Answer (score 12):

I like this solution. It might not be the briefest, but it highlights some functions of the setDate() method on Date() objects that not everybody will be familiar with:

```
function firstDayPreviousMonth(originalDate) {
    var d = new Date(originalDate);
    d.setDate(0); // set to last day of previous month
    d.setDate(1); // set to the first day of that month
    return d;
}
```

It makes use of the fact that .setDate(0) will change the date to point to the last day of the previous month, while .setDate(1) will change it (further) to point to the first day of that month.  It lets the core Javascript libs do the heavy lifting.

You can see a [working Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YmP3RF?p=preview).

Comment: This is weird and unexpected. I like it :)

Answer (score 7):

It will help to get the previous month first and last date.

```javascript
    function getLastMonth(){
        var now = new Date();
        var lastday  = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 0);
        var firstday = new Date(lastday.getFullYear(), lastday.getMonth(), 1);
        var lastMonth = firstday.getDate()+'/'+(firstday.getMonth()+1)+'/'+firstday.getFullYear()+' - '+lastday.getDate()+'/'+(firstday.getMonth()+1)+'/'+lastday.getFullYear();
        return lastMonth;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinventing the wheel?

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) or one of the alternatives (Luxon, Day.js, etc.):

`moment().subtract(1, "months").startOf("months").toDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to use the begging of the month in a BootStrap Min month and didn't want to write it all out.

```js
(() => new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),1, 0))()
```