# Getting the previous month's first date from current date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please anyone share the code to find the previous month's first date from current date in JavaScript. For example, if the current date is 25th Jan 2009, I should get 1st Dec 2008 as result.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605113/find-first-day-of-previous-month-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate [Find first day of previous month in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605113/find-first-day-of-previous-month-in-javascript)

Answer (score 107):

Simplest way would be:

```
var x = new Date();
x.setDate(0); // 0 will result in the last day of the previous month
x.setDate(1); // 1 will result in the first day of the month
```

Comment: This works in all cases I have tested: regular days, 31st of a month, 28th of leap year February, January 1st (rolling back to December of the previous year). It just works and should be the accepted answer. Crazy that this question was posed in 2009.

Comment: Most underappreciated answer I've seen on SO.

Comment: I know slightly off topic but why doesnt this work when setting the date like so:
new Date(2020, 1, 1) but works with new Date()?

Comment: @Mafster Its because month starts at 0. You are actually showing February first.

Comment: Just to clarify to anyone who doesn't understand the approach, this works because `x.setDate(0)` is setting the date to last months last day and since the date is now referencing last month, when you do `x.setDate(1)` it gets you the first day of that month. Pretty nice solution.

Comment: Same principle works for getting a date in the next month using `32` (or more) instead of `0`: `x.setDate(32);` (results in a date near the start of next month)

Answer (score 100):

Straightforward enough, with the [date methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp):

```
  var x = new Date();
  x.setDate(1);
  x.setMonth(x.getMonth()-1);
```

Comment: except it misses when the year changes?

Comment: No it does that will auto adjust the date

Comment: This is why you do this with the native date methods rather than messing around with your own calendar arithmatic. God I love JS :)

Comment: i.e. using his example substitute 1 for 5 say and the year will be 2008

Comment: Unfortunately, using the 'with' keyword is deprecated in late JavaScript versions :( Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552/are-there-legitimate-uses-for-javascripts-with-statement

Comment: I've adapted the example to avoid the `with` keyword.

Comment: also, you should write x.setMonth(x.getMonth()-1); too otherwise there you will end up with an undefined reference

Comment: It's not working when day was become 31 something like day was become 2014-07-31

Comment: @user1699797 - The answer works when setting `x = new Date('2014-07-31')`

Comment: @user8297969 No, it doesn't work. If the current month has 31 days and the previous one has 30 days, then after running date.setMonth(date.getMonth()-1) the date will be equal to the first day of the current month, not the last day of the previous month as expected.

Answer (score 8):

**Important Note: Some of the answers using `setMonth()` here are wrong**:

One liners for use in 2019 (using ES6 syntax; supported by all major browsers and Node):

```
    const date = new Date().toISOString(); // "2019-09-18T13:49:12.775Z"
    const [yyyy, mm, dd, h, i, s] = date.split(/T|:|-/);


    // previous month's last day
    const prev = new Date(new Date().setDate(0)).toISOString();
    const [pyyyy, pmm] = prev.split(/T|:|-/);
```

Note that Array destructuring allows you to skip parts:

```
    const date = new Date().toISOString();
    const [, , dd, , i] = date.split(/T|:|-/);
```

**Explanation**: The code above gets the ISO date `2019-09-18T13:49:12.775Z` and splits it on `:` or `-` or `T` which returns an array `[2019, 09, 18, 13, 49, 12]` which then gets [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

### Using `setMonth()` is wrong:

```
date = new Date("Dec 31, 2019")
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
date; // Dec 1, 2019!
```

Answer (score 6):

Deals with updating year when moving from January to December

```js
var prevMonth = function(dateObj) {
 var tempDateObj = new Date(dateObj);

 if(tempDateObj.getMonth) {
  tempDateObj.setMonth(tempDateObj.getMonth() - 1);
 } else {
  tempDateObj.setYear(tempDateObj.getYear() - 1);
  tempDateObj.setMonth(12);
 }

 return tempDateObj
};

var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
 var x = new Date();
  var prevDate = prevMonth(x.setMonth(i));
 var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 
  "start month/year: " + i + "/" + x.getFullYear() +
  " --- prev month/year: " + prevDate.getMonth() +
  "/" + prevDate.getFullYear() +
  " --- locale prev date: " + prevDate.toLocaleDateString();
  wrapper.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this link:

http://blog.dansnetwork.com/2008/09/18/javascript-date-object-adding-and-subtracting-months/

EDIT: I have drummed up an example:

```
Date.prototype.SubtractMonth = function(numberOfMonths) {
var d = this;
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - numberOfMonths);
d.setDate(1);
return d;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    alert(d.SubtractMonth(1));
});
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, the solution you told returns exact 30 days back from current date. I need first date of the previous month irrespective of any date in current month.

Comment: This solution dose not work. Date.setMonth() dose not accept negative values except -1 which will result in the last month of the previous year
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp

Comment: This answer is buggy, it'll fail for "Dec 31, 2018" for example

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
var curDateMonth = new Date();
var prvDateMonth = new Date(curDateMonth.getFullYear(),curDateMonth.getMonth()-1,curDateMonth.getMonth());
console.log(curDateMonth.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' }) +' vs '+ prvDateMonth.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' }));
```

Answer (score 3):

To get 00:00:00 am of previous month use this:

```
let d = new Date();
d.setDate(1);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
const lastMonthStart = new Date(d);
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

```
//  Previous Month Detail
let prevStartDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() - 1, 1);
console.log(prevStartDate);
let preEndDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() - 1 + 1, 0);
console.log(preEndDate);
//Current Month Detail
let cStartDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), 1);
console.log(cStartDate);
let cEndDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), 1, 0);
console.log(cEndDate);
//Next Month Detail
let nStartDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
console.log(nStartDate);
let nendDate = new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth() + 1 + 1, 0);
console.log(nendDate);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your comment mentions that it works!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @NitinSingh ... It gives both previous month of last first date and end date, so do for current month and next month.

Answer (score 1):

//just try this will work fine

```
let date = new Date();
let month = new Date().getMonth();
let prevMonth = date.setMonth(month - 1)
let formatPrevMonth = new Date(date.setMonth(month - 1));

console.log(formatPrevMonth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, first we assign `getMonth()` to a variable and incremented it by 1:

```js
var currentMonth = date.getMonth()+1;
var current_date = date.getFullYear()+"/"+currentMonth+"/"+date.getDate();
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = "Today,s date:"+current_date;
```

Comment: I see you assume some HTML to be present. But you are sharing only your JS. Can you edit your answer and append your HTML to it as well, preferably in a functional snippet?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved by creating a `Date` object based on the input date object and changing the date to 1, decrementing the year if it was January and decrementing the month (modulo 12). An important addition to it is to subtract the offset as well.

```js
function getFirstOfPreviousMonth(date) {
    let result = new Date(date.getFullYear() - (date.getMonth() ? 0 : 1), (date.getMonth() + 11) % 12, 1);
    return new Date(result.getTime() - result.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
}

console.log(getFirstOfPreviousMonth(new Date()));
console.log(getFirstOfPreviousMonth(new Date(2009, 0, 25)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs 
This code below works for me

```
const onDateButtonClick = (event) => {
if (event) {

  // once on click get the name and use switch case to get date
  var eDate = new Date()
  var sDate;
  var dName = event.target.id;
  switch (dName) {
    case '1w':
      sDate = new Date(eDate.getFullYear(), eDate.getMonth(), eDate.getDate() - 7);
      break;
    case '2w':
      sDate = new Date(eDate.getFullYear(), eDate.getMonth(), eDate.getDate() - 14);
      break;
    case '1m':
      sDate = new Date(eDate.getFullYear(), eDate.getMonth() - 1, eDate.getDate());
      break;
    case '2m':
      sDate = new Date(eDate.getFullYear(), eDate.getMonth() - 2, eDate.getDate());
      break;
  }
}
```