# Javascript date.getYear() returns 111 in 2011?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have this javascript for automatically setting a date filter to the first and last day of the previous month:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DateFrom").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    $("#DateTo").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });

    var now = new Date();
    var firstDayPrevMonth = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth() - 1, 1);
    var firstDayThisMonth = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), 1);
    var lastDayPrevMonth = new Date(firstDayThisMonth - 1);

    $("#DateFrom").datepicker("setDate", firstDayPrevMonth);
    $("#DateTo").datepicker("setDate", lastDayPrevMonth);
});
```

BUT `now.getYear()` is returning 111 instead of the expected 2011.  Is there something obvious I've missed?

Comment: You are apparently the first ever victim of the Y2K bug. I suggest going back in time and gloating.

Comment: How do you know it's returning 111?  Did you try simply doing an alert() after the "var now = new Date()" line?

Comment: @Kelly Try it in your preferred Javascript console.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

> `getYear` is no longer used and has been replaced by the `getFullYear` method.
>
> The `getYear` method returns the year minus 1900; thus:
>
> - For years greater than or equal to 2000, the value returned by `getYear` is 100 or greater. For example, if the year is 2026, `getYear` returns 126.
> - For years between and including 1900 and 1999, the value returned by `getYear` is between 0 and 99. For example, if the year is 1976, `getYear` returns 76.
> - For years less than 1900, the value returned by `getYear` is less than 0. For example, if the year is 1800, `getYear` returns -100.
> - To take into account years before and after 2000, you should use `getFullYear` instead of `getYear` so that the year is specified in full.

Comment: I can't believe a copy-n-paste answer from the manual got 31 upvotes (at the time of writing). Guess it shows how common this issue is and that nobody RTFM... ;o)

Comment: @Mark actually I was using this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605113/find-first-day-of-previous-month-in-javascript that was wrong originally (but it has since been updated to use getFullYear()).  I would never read w3schools for anything :)

Comment: @JK. To be entirely honest, I suspect it was probably me who read W3Schools. Every now and again I delve into there and usually begin regretting it fairly quickly.

Comment: Wow the millenium bug is real, it took 13 years, but this is the first time I see a real life example...

I always used getFullYear before but I wondered what this was (saw it as an autocomplete option).

Answer (score 34):

In order to comply with boneheaded precedent, `getYear()` returns the number of years since 1900.

Instead, you should call `getFullYear()`, which returns the actual year.

Comment: @StevenLu: See the horrors of the original Java Date API

Comment: Wow. Deprecated in the Java API in 1997. Not just 1997, *February* 1997... before 1997 really even got underway... You know, I thought Javascript wasn't really connected to Java...

Answer (score 7):

From what I've read on Mozilla's JS pages, getYear is deprecated. As pointed out many times, `getFullYear()` is the way to go. If you're really wanting to use `getYear()` add 1900 to it.

```
var now = new Date(),
    year = now.getYear() + 1900;
```