# Issue in Parsing date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Javascript getYear() return 108?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98124/why-does-javascript-getyear-return-108)
>   [Javascript date.getYear() returns 111 in 2011?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754938/javascript-date-getyear-returns-111-in-2011)

```
var testDate=new Date("Wed Dec 07 00:00:00 PST 2011")
 testDate.getYear();
```

for the above statement, I am getting 111 while I expect 2011.

Why am getting 111 only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) is [documented to return the year minus 1900](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear), so you are actually getting the expected value. It's also deprecated. Use [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) to receive `2011`.

Answer (score 3):

use `getFullYear()`

```
var testDate=new Date("Wed Dec 07 00:00:00 PST 2011")
testDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 2):

> The getYear method returns the year minus 1900

[Source - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear)

As a better alternative, you can use [getFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).