# What's the difference between JavaScript's getYear() and getFullYear() functions?

Tags: javascript

I was working with JavaScript's `Date` object, and somewhere for the first time I needed to extract the year part of the date. What I saw was a weird behavior. It returns **113** instead of **2013** and I can't figure out how these two numbers might be related, except that the last two numbers might be the same.

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getYear()); // prints 113
console.log(date.getFullYear()); // prints 2013
```

How these functions are different? And why having a function to `getFullYear`? 
It just makes no sense to me to get *part* of a year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript date.getYear() returns 111 in 2011?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754938/javascript-date-getyear-returns-111-in-2011)

Comment: Note that on IE8 it doesn't make difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Javascript getYear() return 108?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98124/why-does-javascript-getyear-return-108)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> It just makes no sense to me to get part of a year.

Back in the day, when memory was expensive and the Year 2000 was far in the future, it did make sense for people to represent 1975 as 75. In retrospect a short-sighted decision.

```
date.getFullYear() == date.getYear() + 1900
```

Comment: it's really a short-sighted decision!

Answer (score 8):

`getYear()` returns year minus `1900`. This has been deprecated for a while now, it's best to use `getFullYear()`.

Answer (score 3):

Its a Y2K thing, basically `getYear` method returns the year minus 1900.

so, I encourage to move over to `getFullYear` & use that instead.