# How to get Javascript current date Seconds , in a particular format

Tags: javascript

How can i get

**Year** **Month** **Date** **Seconds** ??

So that it looks like this

```
14062154
```

When  tried it this way

```
function myFunction() {


var dt = new Date();

alert(dt.getYear() +  dt.getMonth() + 1  + dt.getDate()+ dt.getSeconds());
}
```

The result was 201 Could anybody please let me kniw how can i make correction ??

Comment: Do you want in long format?

Comment: This may be adding the numeric values of each component, as opposed to concatenating them as if they were strings.  If you want to force concatenation, "add" in a empty string or 2.

Comment: do you think it magically gets converted to seconds?

Comment: That's a strange format... Why are the hours and minutes not included?

Answer (score 2):

All of those function return numbers, and what happens when you put a `+` sign between numbers - it adds them.

Try turning them into strings first so they are concatenated, not added

i.e.

```
function myFunction() {    
var dt = new Date();    
alert(dt.getYear().toString() +  (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString()  + dt.getDate().toString() + dt.getSeconds().toString());
}
```

A couple of other points as per comments

`.getYear()` is old and shouldn't really be used (see SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754938/javascript-date-getyear-returns-111-in-2011)), it returns 114 for 2014, you should use `.getFullYear()`, this will return 2014, but since you may only want a two digit year, trim the first two characters off

Something like:

```
function myFunction() {    
var dt = new Date();    
alert(dt.getYear().toString().substr(2) +  (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString()  + dt.getDate().toString() + dt.getSeconds().toString());
}
```

Assuming you are tring to keep a set format of 2 digits for year, 2 digits for month, 2 digits for day and 2 digits for seconds, if any of these are below 10, you will need to pad with a zero. So I would make a helper function to pad,

Something like:

```
function pad(s, size) {    
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

then you can add it to your function

Something like:

```
function myFunction() {    
var dt = new Date();    
alert(pad(dt.getYear().toString().substr(2),2) +  pad((dt.getMonth() + 1).toString(),2)  + pad(dt.getDate().toString(),2) + pad(dt.getSeconds().toString(),2));
}
```

Comment: The output of the above code is not exactly the same format as the above example you've given. You might consider this one: http://jsfiddle.net/TvMLE/ :))

Comment: if the month, date and seconds are in single digit, then it would come as 114654 where 114 is getYear, 6 is month, 5 is date and 4 is seconds

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this,

```
function addZeros(val)
{
    val    = ""+val;
    return val.length === 1 ? "0"+val : val;
}

function myFunction() 
{

 var dt = new Date();

 alert(dt.getUTCFullYear().toString().slice(2)+ addZeros(dt.getMonth()+1)+addZeros(dt.getDate())+ addZeros(dt.getSeconds()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a timestamp? Javascript natively uses a timestamp in milliseconds, this could result in less code.

```
var timestamp_milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
```

if you want the timestamp to be in seconds, just divid by 1000;

```
var timestamp_seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also build an array and then join it, this is a little less code.

```
function getTimestamp() {

  var dt = new Date();


  return [dt.getYear(), dt.getMonth() + 1, dt.getDate(), dt.getSeconds()].join('');

}
```