# Angularjs next and previous day,year,month

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter

Using the Angular date `$filter` actually i can get the current `day, year and month`.

But, how can i get the next and previous `day, year, month`?

This is the code i wrote but i dont know where to start with

```
$scope.month = $filter('date')(date, 'MMMM');//December-November like
$scope.day = $filter('date')(date, 'dd'); //01-31 like
$scope.year = $filter('date')(date,'yyyy');//2014 like

$scope.nextYear = Number($scope.year) + 1;
$scope.prevYear = Number($scope.year) - 1;
$scope.nextDay = ?
etc...
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: you can use `http://www.datejs.com/` plugin :) or `http://momentjs.com/docs/` :)

Comment: +1 for using moment.js, you will save your time, simplify your code, and to the tricks rightly !

Comment: @benek nah i am building a directive and it must work without helps ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do it like this, angular date $filter doesn't offer you any easier way of doing it, it just formats a date in a custom desired format.

Day:

```
var myDate = new Date();

var previousDay = new Date(myDate);

previousDay.setDate(myDate.getDate()-1);

var nextDay = new Date(myDate);

nextDay.setDate(myDate.getDate()+1);
```

Month:

```
var previousMonth = new Date(myDate);

previousMonth.setMonth(myDate.getMonth()-1);

var nextMonth = new Date(myDate);

nextMonth.setMonth(myDate.getMonth()+1);
```

Year:

```
var previousYear = new Date(myDate);

previousYear.setYear(myDate.getFullYear()-1);

var nextYear = new Date(myDate);

nextYear.setYear(myDate.getFullYear()+1);

$scope.month = $filter('date')(myDate, 'MMMM');//December-November like
$scope.day = $filter('date')(myDate, 'dd'); //01-31 like
$scope.year = $filter('date')(myDate,'yyyy');//2014 like

$scope.nextDay = $filter('date')(nexyDay, 'dd');
$scope.prevDay = $filter('date')(previousDay, 'dd');
$scope.nextMonth = $filter('date')(nextMonth, 'MMMM')
$scope.prevMonth = $filter('date')(previousMonth, 'MMMM')
$scope.nextYear = $filter('date')(nextYear,'yyyy');
$scope.prevYear = $filter('date')(previousYear,'yyyy');
```

If you are going to do this a lot, I suggest you create a service to implement this logic.

Comment: @Wavy do you  even know how to increment the month for example $scope.month = $scope.month+1 ? i tryed something like **$scope.month = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.month).getMonth()+1, 'MMMM');**

Comment: My answer tells you how :s

`var nextMonth = new Date(date);
$scope.nextMonth = $filter('date')(nextMonth.setDate(date.getMonth()+1), 'MMMM')`

Comment: I was able to make this work after changing the `getYear()` method to `getFullYear()`.  `getYear()` returns the number of years since 1900 and is deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754956/3341707