# How to bind date to kendo datepicker

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendodatepicker.below is my code.

```
<input id="datePicker" />
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
  value: new Date(),
  min: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
  max: new Date(2049, 11, 31)
 })
});
```

I want to put the datepicker default selected value as last month start date .please give me an idea.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I do recommend take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/605121/1802671 as a solution for getting the first day of previous month including months as January and other corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var d = new Date().setDate(-1);

 $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
   value: new Date(d),
   min: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
   max: new Date(2049, 11, 31)
 })
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
  var d = new Date().setDate(-1);

  $("#datePicker").attr('value',new Date(d));
  $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
});
```

probably it works in super short way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
   $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
     value: new Date().setDate(-1),
     min: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
     max: new Date(2049, 11, 31)
   })
 });
```

have fun

Comment: `setDate(-1)` is the last day of previous month, isn't it? I think that Sid was asking by the first and not the last.

Answer (score 1):

First get current date using Date() and then subtract a month and then set it to the first of the month.

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> var lastMonthStart = new Date();
> with(lastMonthStart) {
>     setMonth(getMonth()-1);
>     setDate(1);
> }
> $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
>     value: lastMonthStart,
>     min: new Date(1950, 0, 1),
>     max: new Date(2049, 11, 31)
> }) });
> ```

Should give you the start of last month.