# First and last dates using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

1. How to get First date and last date of previous month using javascript?
2. How to get First date and last date of current month using javascript?
3. How to get first and last dates of previous quarter?
4. How to get first and last dates of current quarter?
5. How to get first and last dates of previous Year?
6. How to get first and last dates of current Year?
   Please suggest me on any/all of the above questions.

Comment: What you should do is make your question a little bit more generic. That might help.

Comment: You should post what you have tried so we know how to help you. A shopping list of things you need done aren't for stackoverflow.com

Comment: For previous month, I used the following thing -- var today = new date(); var firstday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 1); this dint work.

Comment: For previous Week Dates I used following code                            var curr = new Date; 
   var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay()-7; 
   var last = first + 6; 
   var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first));
   var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)); ===== This worked.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this library it should help you with those questions.

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks. But, this needs additional Javascripts to be added in to the project. I need just some functions which can do this job.!

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = new Date();
var year= x.getYear();
var month = x.getMonth();
var day = x.getDate();
var prevMonthFirstDay = new Date(year - (month == 1 ? 1 : 0), (month == 12 ? 1 : month - 1), 1);
var prevMonthLastDay = new Date(year, month, 0);
var thisMonthFirstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
var thisMonthLastDay = new Date(year + (month == 12 ? 1 : 0), (month == 1 ? 12 : month + 1), 0);
```

Use same things for others. i.e. for quarter use 4 instead of 1 for month...

Comment: alert('===='+prevMonthFirstDay); gives ==== Sun Jul 31 0112 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) as answer. But it should give me August 1 2012.

Comment: Yeah! I Just used 0 instead of 1 in first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive answers for all of your questions from here
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605113/find-first-day-of-previous-month-in-javascript

Comment: Hi, I tried using new Date(yourDate.getFullYear(), yourDate.getMonth() - 1, 1); But this dint work.

Comment: var firstday = new Date().setDate(1).setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1); alert(firstday);

Answer (score 0):

1. How to get First date and last date of previous month using javascript?

   ```
   firstDate = new Date().setDate(1).setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1);
   ```
2. How to get First date and last date of current month using javascript?
3. How to get first and last dates of previous quarter?
4. How to get first and last dates of current quarter?
5. How to get first and last dates of previous Year?
6. How to get first and last dates of current Year?

Comment: var firstday = new Date().setDate(1).setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1); alert(firstday); Nothing happened upon using this code..

Comment: Oh... Just a sec... Try this: `firstDay = new Date(); firstDay.setDate(1); firstDay.setMonth(firstDay.getMonth()-1); alert(firstDay);`

Comment: What about the last date of previous month? Any idea?

Comment: Beware: setDate(x) fails under some circumstances, so it is better to use Date(yyyy,m,x). We had a problem using setDate(-1) on Mac Safari, but only on some months.

Comment: @robocat Commenting on this after 3 years?