# How to get three month ago date in javascript in the format as YYYYDDMM efficiently

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I know a way to do in java:

```
Calendar c5 = Calendar.getInstance();
c5.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);
c5.getTime(); //It will give YYYYMMDD format three months ago.
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript. I know that I can use
Date d = new Date(); parse it and do some code to get the format.
But now I dont want to do parsing  and getting three month ago date.

Comment: Sure you can use a library like [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) which is probably around 25kb of stuff you will not use to do something 5 lines of JavaScript can do.

Comment: @epascarello I really want to see your 5 line javascript code with all edge cases covered ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var dt = new Date('13 June 2013');
dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth()-1)
```

Then you can use this piece of code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3067896/219118) to convert it to YYYYMMDD

```
 Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
   var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
   return yyyy + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
  };

d = new Date();
d.yyyymmdd();
```

Something to be careful of. If you're at Mar 31 and subtract a month, what happens? You can't get Feb 31! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499846/219118) answer for more details.