# How to match a date between given date difference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a script that calculates the number of weeks between two given dates.

and then creates a table where number of row equals number of weeks .

script looks like this

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2pkv17a/2/)

**Script**

```
$('#test').click(function () {

    // Here are the two dates to compare
    var date1 = '29-10-2015';
    var date2 = '29-12-2015';
    var Targetvalue = parseFloat("1000000");
        var dealjson = '[{"dealdate":"25-11-2015","cost":200000}]';

    // First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
    date1 = date1.split('-');
    date2 = date2.split('-');

    // Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
    date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1], date1[0]);
    date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1], date2[0]);

    // We use the getTime() method and get the unixtime (in milliseconds, but we want seconds, therefore we divide it through 1000)
    date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime() / 1000);
    date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);

    // This is the calculated difference in seconds
    var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;

    // in Hours
    var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;

    // and finaly, in days :)
    var timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours / 24;
    var timeDifferenceInWeeks = Math.round(timeDifferenceInDays / 7);
    // alert(timeDifferenceInDays/7);
    TargetPerweek = Targetvalue / timeDifferenceInWeeks;
    //Math.round(timeDifferenceInWeeks);
    TargetPerweek = Math.round(TargetPerweek * 100) / 100;
    var string = "<table data-role='table' class='ui-responsive'><thead><tr><th>Week</th><th>Target</th><th>Achieved</th></tr></thead>";
    for (var i = 1; i <= timeDifferenceInWeeks; i++)
    string = string + "<tr><th>Week" + i + "</th><td>" + TargetPerweek + "</td><td></td></tr>";

    string = string + "</table>";
    $('.varianceData').html(string);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="test">See the Tab</button>
<div class="varianceData"></div>
```

If you click the button in the fiddle you will see a table with Target and achieved value week wise .

So I want to show the achieved on the respective week he did the deal

Based on the variable `dealjson` so in the achived column I should show the amount that was achieved in the respective week ;

**Expected Out put based on the dealjson**

```
<table data-role="table" class="ui-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Week</th>
            <th>Target</th>
            <th>Achieved</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Week1</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td>No Deal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week2</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td>No Deal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week3</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week4</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td>No Deal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week5</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td>200000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week6</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week7</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td>No Deal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week8</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td>No Deal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Week9</th>
            <td>111111.11</td>
            <td>No Deal</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @ManProgrammer I updated my question please have a look

Comment: How could you decided **No Deal** Shows or not

Comment: @ManProgrammer using the `dealJson` if the dates from the variable matches the week its falling in then I should show the `cost' else I should show `No deal `

Comment: For comparing dates, you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/493018/3207406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setDate()` to increase the number of `date1` 7 days, until it becomes equal to or greater than `date2`. And compare the deal dates using simple `>= && <=`, to check if the dates is within the week, you will need a temporary variable.
Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2pkv17a/3/). Its not optimized, but it works.

Comment: So now IF i have more number of achived values in Json it should work right ?

Comment: Yes the code in the fiddle should work for an array of deals in dealjson.

Comment: actually in Target week wise should be Target/totalweek can you tell me how i can do that here

Comment: You can use an array of achieved values  and create the to be appended string outside the loop, when you have the achieved values and the number of weeks. Or you just find the number of weeks in the way you did earlier.

Comment: one Last thing Can you please add thelogic to make one table month wise and day wise . I tried but I am not able to do it.

Comment: For days you can change the number of days being added to 1. Doing this for months is bit trickier, you can follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499838/javascript-date-next-month) . If you can use a library, then [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) will help.

Comment: @AkshendraPratab I tried with multiple json data but its not working , Please check this  fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k2pkv17a/6/

Comment: 25-10-2015 does not come within the specified does, try 29-10-2015

Comment: I am sorry I think wrong data in my Database , I will try to build for day wise and month wise , I have to show all this in a graph so Can You suggest something  Please

Comment: I have not used a JS charting library myself but there are tons of them. One that I have heard a lot about is [Chart.js] (http://www.chartjs.org/), take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92248/discussion-between-vikram-and-akshendra-pratap).